# ModuleNotFoundError - Python

Tags: python, importerror

Here is my file structure...

```
my_project/
├── app1/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── module.py [class Tokens]
└── app2/
    ├── __init__.py
    └── feature1/
        ├── __init__.py
        └── script.py
```

In script.py, I have to import Tokens...

What I tried is:
`from app1.module import Tokens`
also
`from my_project.app1.module import Tokens`

I am getting: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app1' or 'my_porject'

Why am I getting this error and how do I resolve it.

Comment: Can you check your cwd (current working directory)? There are many ways, but you can try `import os;print(os.getcwd())`. If the cwd is the (absolute) path of the `my_project` folder, let us know.

Comment: Yes it is the absolute path...

Comment: Just to confirm, you used `from my_project...` not `form my_project...` (I think you did use `from`?) and that the `ModuleNotFoundError` you listed is from the second import statement? Also can you show me the output of `import os;print....`?

Comment: Sorry that was typing error in question... No I am getting it from both the import statements and the output is
```C:\Users\Harsh\VSCode\tdc\The-Project\my_project```

Comment: Ok I think I have a solution, give me a sec.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\Harsh\VSCode\tdc\The-Project\my_project')
from module import Token
```

Let me know if this works!

Reference: [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Comment: This is both not necessary and probably wrong. You shouldn't need to add to `sys.path` when importing from within a package and the path you append is relative to the running directory so who's to say there is even a `app1` directory there?

Comment: Now also getting the same error but for moule

Comment: Try replace `.\\app1` with the absolute path? I'll edit my answer

Comment: @Tomerikoo I've edited the answer, and if you have a better answer, please make a suggestion. I'll be happy to remove my answer if your\ option is more appropriate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time here are 12 answers